# Why doesn't Nginx reverse proxy on WSL2 see Rails app in Docker Container using hostname?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx-reverse-proxy, wsl-2

I've got several Rails websites running in Docker dev containers. Docker is running in WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) on Windows 11. Nginx is running in Ubuntu as a reverse proxy, IIS is turned off in Windows. The Ubuntu /etc/hosts file is automatically populated from the hosts file in Windows. It is set up like this because others on the team are running Linux on Macs but I switch between Rails and .Net development.

An example website is mysite1.localhost which is exposed on port 8081 on Docker and there is an entry of '127.0.0.1   mysite1.localhost' in both hosts files.

**The problem I have is browsing (Chrome on Windows) localhost:8081 returns 200 from the website, great, but using the hostname mysite1.localhost returns 502 Bad Gateway.**

I am assuming Nginx doesn't know about Docker or something like that?

Here is the mysite1.conf for Nginx:

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name mysite1.localhost;
     
     resolver 127.0.0.1;
     
     location ~* "^/shared-nav" {
         proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/stuff$is_args$args;
       }
     
     location / {
         ssi on;
         
         ssi_silent_errors off;
         log_subrequest on;
     
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
         add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
     
         if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?/([^/]*?)$) {
           set $filename $1;
         }
         if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)|(woff2)$) {
           add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
         }
       }
 }
```

I can see two problems in nginx/error.log:

2023/02/02 08:50:10 [warn] 2841#2841: conflicting server name "mysite1.localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

2023/02/02 08:50:12 [error] 2845#2845: *52 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ::1, server: mysite1.localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "mysite1.localhost"

It doesn't seem to matter whether or not docker is running.

For the conflicting server name waring, I've tried looking for temporary files that need deleting but cannot find anything.

Most of the other questions I've looked at involve solving problems with containerized Nginx where as this is sitting in WSL.

Please let me know if I can better explain the problem, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I didn't take into consideration was using VS Code to dev in the containers means that the ports were forwarded to Windows - although the containers are running in WSL, VS Code is running in Windows.

So, I could either turn IIS back on and use it as a reverse proxy or try Nginx for Windows. I've opted for the latter as it means I can share the same config files as the Linux guys and will see how it works out, for now I can browse the websites by hostname.

If anyone else needs to work with this set up, I'm happy to pass on my experiences.